# Is it possible to compile a specific closure to wasm in rust?

Tags: rust, webassembly

Here's my `main` function as

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let z = 123;

    let w: Vec<_> = v
        .iter()
        .map(|x| {
            // closure A
            println!("v = {x}");
            z + x * x
        })
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", w);
}
```

> The closure enclosing comment `closure A` may reference other crates' APIs sometimes.

Is there a way to compile only the closure enclosing comment `closure A` (rather than the whole `main` function) to WebAssembly?

Comment: And then do what with it?

Comment: And then send it through RPC to run in another service equipped with a wasm VM, or anything like that @ChayimFriedman

Comment: So you want to get a compiled WASM in bytes for some function? Create a new project and invoke rustc with it with WASM as target. You cannot compiler a closure - it is not just code, also data.

Comment: I agree with @ChayimFriedman. You are mixing two compilation targets here; you have to decide if something is code or data. And if you want to send it over network, then it is data, not code. So you need another project to compile the code to data.

Comment: Although I suspect that this is an X/Y-problem, the usecase seems rather strange the way you present it here

Comment: Actually, I want to find out it's possible implement serializing/deserialize any rust closure like that in java as https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-serialize-a-lambda-function-in-java#:~:text=The%20Serialization%20is%20a%20process,its%20captured%20arguments%20have%20serialized. @Finomnis

Comment: How is Java connected to this?

Comment: For reference only. Because in java a closure can be serialized during runtime, and then sent to remote where the serialized codes will be deserialized and run. I want to achieve something alike in rust directly or indirectly by wasm. @Finomnis

Comment: Interesting. Well I'm unsure how they achieved that tbh ... I don't think it's possible in a language as strict as rust. Executing binary code that you got sent over the network definitely falls under the category 'undefined behaviour'. It might be possible with `unsafe` and function pointers, but even then. Rust does not have an immediate representation that gets interpreted at runtime. It compiles directly to bytecode, so in the best case it's not portable between machines, and in the worst case you directly implement a backdoor.